# Does the .length method in a for loop, imply iterating through an array?

Tags: javascript

Given the twoSum problem

```
const nums = [2, 7, 11, 15];
const target = 9;

var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for(let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] === target) {
                return [i, j]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

where "i < nums.length" is it correct that we've now altered what type of input the nums argument will take? as 'function (nums, target)' is passing two arguments - is it now expecting the first argument to be an array?

Comment: It will expect the `nums` parameter to have a `length` property on it. An array type will satisfy this requirement.

Comment: thanks! question closed